# Reading endpoint from config file in workflow service

Tags: c#, web-services, workflowservice

I know how can I read information from the config file in the activities by using C#

```
 var servicesSection = (ClientSection)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/client");
 ChannelEndpointElement endpoint = servicesSection.Endpoints[0];
```

But when I try to read this information in the if statement of the workflow service, it doesn't work. 
I tried the following code to read the endpoint information from the web.config file.

```
((ClientSection)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/client")).Endpoints[0].toString().Equals("");
```

but it doesn't work. 
some how, it doesn't understand the type casting and I can't convert the GetSection output to a clientSection object. do you know how can I do that in the if statement of the workflow service?( check something from the config file before calling some other activities)

Comment: By the way, I already added all the references that I needed and I get the following compilation error : ')' expected

Answer (score 0):

I had similar requirement, after some prototyping, I managed following way. Hope this will help you and others.

```
/* Using in System.ServiceModel.dll */
    using System.ServiceModel.Configuration;
    using System.Web.Configuration;

    /* Inside any method  */
    var clientSection = ((ClientSection)(WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/client")));
                if (clientSection != null)
                {
                    foreach (ChannelEndpointElement endPoint in clientSection.Endpoints)
                    {
                        ..... endPoint.Name / endPoint.Address etc.
                    }
                }
```

You can read any element from configuration and cast it to appropriate element type.

Answer (score 0):

To read endpoint, binding and other sections from app.config, there are defined set of Section classes that help us read settings.

For example, to read list of bindings, we could simply use,

```
private void GetNetTcpBindingName()
    {
        Configuration appConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        ServiceModelSectionGroup serviceModel = ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(appConfig);
        BindingsSection oBinding = serviceModel.Bindings;

        List<BindingCollectionElement> bindingCollection = oBinding.BindingCollections;

        NetTcpBindingCollectionElement netTCPBindingCollectionElement = (NetTcpBindingCollectionElement)bindingCollection.Where(obj => obj.BindingName.Equals("netTcpBinding")).SingleOrDefault();

        if (netTCPBindingCollectionElement != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(netTCPBindingCollectionElement.ConfiguredBindings.ElementAt(0).Name);
        }
    }
```

Given the following app.config XML (section of interest in bold),

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITrainerManagement" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
      **<netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_ILiveStream">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>**
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://sever-pc/PST.TS.LiveStream/LiveStream.svc"
          binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_ILiveStream"
          contract="LiveStreamServiceReference.ILiveStream" name="NetTcpBinding_ILiveStream" />
      <endpoint address="http://10.5.50.115/PST.TS.TrainerService/TrainerManagement.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITrainerManagement"
          contract="TrainerManagementServiceReference.ITrainerManagement"
          name="BasicHttpBinding_ITrainerManagement" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Hope this helps. This can be used to read any standard settings.